# Unit Testing Echo Function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, echo

To be more specific I am working on an assignment involving unit testing. These are the test cases I'm currently working on:

```
#include "c-echo.h"

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(EchoTest, HelloWorld) {
    char* test_val[3]; test_val[0] = "./c-echo"; test_val[1] = "hello"; test_val[2] = "world";
    EXPECT_EQ("hello world", echo(3.test_val));
}

TEST(EchoTest, EmptyString) {
        char* test_val[1]; test_val[0] = "./c-echo";
        EXPECT_EQ("", echo(1.test_val));
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

c-echo.h program:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string echo(int length, char** chars) {
    std::string ret = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        ret += chars[i];
        if(i < length - 1) {
            ret += " ";
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The assignment stated that I needed to include three additional test cases (edge cases in particular) for the echo function. However, I can't seem to think of any. I'm really new to this whole testing thing.

Thank You

Comment: I can think of edge cases: 1. Zero count of `chars`. And to break the function: 2. `INT_MAX` count of `chars`.

Comment: Do you have an actual specification of how `echo` should behave which would describe what happens on unusual inputs? Or just what you can infer from its implementation?